# Pandas: How to return the row from dataframe having same row values by using column value of other dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'country': ['EUR.1M', 'EUR.1M', 'EUR.3M','EUR.3M','EUR.6M','EUR.6M','USD.3M', 'USD.3M', 'USD.3M', 
                        'HKD.3M','HKD.3M','HKD.3M','GBP.6M', 'GBP.6M','GBP.6M'], 
       'inst': ['base', 'base', 'depo', 'Fut', 'Fut','base', 'irs','base', 'irs','Fut', 'irs', 'irs',
                'irs','Fut', 'irs'],
       'frequency' : ['Eur35Y', 'Eur40Y', 'Eur12Y','Eur10Y','Eur20Y','Eur40Y','USDIRS23Y', 'USDswap15Y','USD20Y',
                      'HKD50Y', 'HKD20Y','HKD10Y','GBP19Y', 'GBPIRS15Y','GBP60Y']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'tenor': ['Eur40Y','HKD50Y']})
```

I have two dataframes mentioned above and I am interested in two columns from df1 ('country'and 'frequency'). However, am trying to pull values from column 'country' from df1 by comparing df2. The objective is if any one value in df2 is present in df1['frequency'], then I dont want to pick the values from df['country']. For example: If the 'tenor' value is similar to 'frequency' then I dont want the associated 'country' values from df1.
I am new to the pandas and picking up fast. Seeking expected output as below. Please suggest.

```
list = ['EUR.3M','USD.3M','GBP.6M']
```

Comment: check with isin + tolist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

```
s = df1.loc[df1["frequency"].isin(df2["tenor"]),"country"]

print (df1.loc[~df1["country"].isin(s),"country"].unique().tolist())

#['EUR.3M', 'USD.3M', 'GBP.6M']
```